# saving pictures in Core Data in 'to-many relationship' environment

Tags: iphone, core-data, uiimage, save, one-to-many

I'm working on my small project which take pictures and save them, very simple, using Core Data. I have two entities; one is 'Person' and the other is 'Image'. the relationship from Person  to Image is to-many and from Image to Person I got inverse relationship as well.

All I need at the moment is to ***add multiple number of images (taken from iphone camera or chosen from library) to one Person entity***.

I'd like to know whether there is any kind of sample code that deals with to-many relationship with UIImage using Core Data.

many thanks.

=====================

Actually I wish I could specify the problem. What i'm trying to do is using access methods that are given for free in to-many relationship to add object such as

```
- (void)addPersonImageObject:(PersonImage *)value;
```

and also I've implemented methods related to ImageToDataTransformer.

I spent almost a week on this matter and I think I need a guiding sample code that I can study first for my add project.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is. Are you having trouble encoding UIImage objects to NSData objects? Or are you having trouble creating to-many relationships from Parent to Image? In the abstract, these are two unrelated problems. Also, are you subclassing NSManagedObject and creating classes Parent and Image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides converting the `UIImage` to `NSData` and back there is nothing special by having a to-many relationship with `UIImage`s. So any core data tutorial that includes a to-many relationship should suffice. If you need sample code you can check out Apple's [iPhoneCoreDataRecipes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html).

A few pointers to help you get started. Let's pretend we have a `PersonViewController` that inherits from a `UITableViewController' that gets called with something like:

```
PersonViewController *personViewController = [[[PersonViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
personViewController.person = ... // get the selected person
personViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:personViewController animated:YES];
```

PersonViewController has the following properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Person *person;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *images;
```

There is add button which would shod the image picker

```
- (void)insertNewObject {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}
```

Then in the callback `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` we can:

```
// Get the image from the picker
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

// Transform the image to NSData
ImageToDataTransformer *transformer = [[[ImageToDataTransformer alloc] init] autorelease];
NSData *imageData = [transformer transformedValue:image];

// Create a new PersonImage entity and assign the image data    
PersonImage *personImage = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PersonImage" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
personImage.imageData = imageData;

// This is where we are adding the image to our person  
[self.person addImagesObject:personImage];

// Core data save, however you want to do it.
NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    abort();
}

// simple trick to update the table view data source    
self.images = nil;
[self.tableView reloadData];
// don't forget to dismiss the picker
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

The implementation of `images` just to keep it simple

```
- (NSArray *)images {
    if (images_) {
        return images_;
    }

    // since we set self.images = nil when adding a new image we will get the list
    // of all images from our person object. 
    images_ = [[self.person.images allObjects] retain];
    return images_;
}
```

The table view data source methods would just be:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.images.count;
}
```

and however the cell is created doesn't really matter. At then if we wanted to do something with the images we can do something in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  // get the tapped person image    
  PersonImage *personImage = [self.images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  // get the image
  ImageToDataTransformer *transformer = [[[ImageToDataTransformer alloc] init] autorelease];
  UImage *image = [transformer reverseTransformedValue:personImage.imageData];
  // do something with the image.

}
```

Comment: cheers Robert. let me chk my imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo based on your code. Mine is quite similar to yours but there must be something I'm missing. please come and chk later on.

Comment: what I missed was I did't change image data to NSData before 'personImage.imageData = imageData;'. seems like there is no warning or error message, so let me ask you one question. You used NSArray images to fetch PersonImage later on. I don't know why we need it because once we save multiple number of images of one person into Core Data using to-Many relationship, then there must be a way to get those images same way.

Comment: I think I got it. just managed to save multiple images to on entity and checked them one by one. great! (still lot of things to be done of course) 'Besides converting the UIImage to NSData and back there is nothing special by having a to-many relationship with UIImages.' , your code and CoreDataRecipe (every time I look at this sample it gives me something new...) were 'very' helpful. thank you.

Comment: on the second trial. it was 'adding and checking' multiple number of images to one entity that I succeeded not 'saving'. to add and to save is different..so I posted another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282416/iphone-saving-data-in-to-many-relationship-core-data . cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Images from the camera could be really big. General rule to images in Core Data is below 1 MB. You might want to store the image in a directory and store the path in Core Data.

Comment: when I test my app that has one person and one image (one to one relationship) on device, performance was not that bad. thanks a lot for advice..too many stuff to learn....