# Saving NSData Array to CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm picking an image from gallery and converting it to `NSData`. Later on I'm storing it in CoreData and retrieving later. But if I pick 2 images from the gallery, I want to store the `NSData info of both of them to an array and store that array to CoreData. But how an array can be saved to CoreData that I'm not able to figure out. Did go through other SO posts dealing with similar issue but they weren't of much help.

Also please note..I cannot store the array to `Userdefaults` or `Document directory` in this scenario because there are other data associated with the image like name,qty etc. and they are all stored in coredata and they should later be displayed in tableview. If just the images are stored using some other method and the other details stored using core-data, there won't be proper data populated in the tableview..

Comment: This link can help you... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266205/saving-pictures-in-core-data-in-to-many-relationship-environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use entity as `ImagesArray` with `relationship` to many entities as `Image`. In its turn, the picture will have properties e.g. `imageData (Binary Data)`, `Name (String)` etc. and `relationship` to one `ImagesArray`.

See [example](http://github.com/kudlay/Images-in-Core-Data)

Create `ImagesArray` entity with `identifier` or other properties for identification.

[image]

And then create `Image` entity with properties `imageData` (Binary Data), `name` (String) etc.

[image]

Entity `ImagesArray` will have `relationship` `images` to many entities `Image`.

Entity `Image` will have inverse `relationship` `imagesArray` to one entity `ImagesArray`

[image]

In code you will create `set` of entities `Image` with `imageData`, `name` etc.

Then create `ImagesArray`.

Add `set` of entities `Image` to `ImagesArray`'s property (relationship) `images`.

Entity `ImagesArray` will have `set` of entities `Image`.

Comment: can u explain in a bit more detail, @Alexey Kudlay

Comment: @bvt, OK. A little bit later

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Alexey Kudlay..I got some idea of what u said but not everything. In this case which array will hold my images..? The array of type `Image` or `Images`..? Also, how images will be stored..? in `NSData` format or as images itself..?

Comment: @bvt, I did refresh answer. 

Also, how images will be stored..? - `NSData`

Comment: @bvt, did my decision help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163456/discussion-between-bvt-and-alexey-kudlay).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion saving an image to CoreData is not a correct approach to save images. You should save them in the app sand box and then store in CoreData the path.
Saying that you can save an Array by using NSValueTransformer, you can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726611/saving-an-array-with-core-data-swift-3). but probably the best approach is to create a relation between a User entity and Image entity One-to-Many.

Comment: I did see that link already @Andrea but couldn't get much help from it..